# Prevent loading of nested iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe which has arbitrary content:

```
<iframe src-doc="whatever"></iframe>
```

It gets annoying when there's an iframe inside it.

```
<iframe id="test" srcdoc="&lt;iframe src=&quot;http://apple.com&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"></iframe>
```

So how can I prevent that? Is there a better way to pre-filtering the srcdoc?

Comment: Try a regular expression?

Comment: @PHearst That's what I ended up doing. Not very versatile.

Comment: Nope, but I don't think there's any other way to filter it.